# Computer won't start (keeps restarting)

Tags: boot, hardware-failure

I have a computer with a MSI motherboard. I tried to put another hard-disk with a regular port using a cable wich has 2 regular outs because I have just one regular port on the motherboard but 4 sata ports.

I don't know if I touched something else than the motherboard connection and the power source of the cd-rom and of the hard-disk I tried to insert. I removed the hard-disk and now it keeps restarting.

The computer restarts after just a few seconds of functioning (I know that because the CD-ROM gets stucked when I open it and after a while it opens or close automatically like there is a boot try).

The computer screen shows nothing, it does not get signal.

After I tried to reconnect everything, it booted fine once but after a while the screen started showing some pink and purple lines in the middle. After I restarted it started to malfunction again like described. Any ideas?

Comment: Eeww, doesn't sound good.  Is there anyway to inspect the temp of your system?  Are you even able to get to the BIOS?  Have you reseated everything other than the CPU?  Reset the BIOS?

Comment: can you elaborate on "regular port" are you talking about IDE? Do you have two devices hooked up to the same IDE port? Or are you talking about power (molex)?

Comment: The temperature of the system is the room temperature. Can't get to the BIOS. I have reseated what I have used, I didn't even playd with the CPU. REmoved the cmos battery and reinserted, no luck.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about IDE, I forgot hot it was named. I tried to have 2 devices on the same IDE port but it didn't worked so I reverted to the cable that had just 1 device-connecting port. There are any differences between the molexes or they are all the same?

Comment: Obvious question, but, are you setting your jumper settings on you devices correctly (master/slave)?  Back in my youth, I have rendered a mobo inopperable by failing to make the proper changes to my drives when add/swapping things out.

Comment: The thing is that now there shouldn't be any changes than before inserting that new hard-drive. Any pictures would help?

Comment: Also it emits a wierd sound when it first starts.

Comment: Hydroparadise, can I change those settings without accesing BIOS?

Comment: Also with all the cables removed from harddrive and cdrom it wont start.

Comment: http://support.seagate.com/kbimg/M_b.gif  is a generaly picture of jumper settings on the drive.  You will need to consult a manual of the specific make an model of your drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your issues seem to sprout at P.O.S.T and the system did start for a bit then revert to it's no start situation and with the addition of a "weird sound" at "power on", the situation is pointing to one of many potential sources.

The power supply unit. Even though fans may spin (and I bet, if you can pin point that noise, it's coming from the PSU) and stuff looks like it's happening, a bad PSU will give you problems like you are experiencing.